# How can I run casperjs javascript tests from Jenkins?

Tags: django, jenkins, phantomjs, casperjs, ghost.py

I've written some casperjs tests to test my Django application. If the Django application is started (on port 8000 for example), casperjs can be run as a separate process and access my running Django app.

My other tests are written with Django's (web)testing framework that sets up the test database with  fixtures, and are run with `./manage.py test`. With Django webtest, you don't need to start a separate Django webserver (doing requests and url routing is proxied/simulated).

Is there a way to rung casperjs tests from within Django webtest? Without starting a different webserver and having yet another test database?

I've seen ghost.py exists, but haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to find a solution. After upgrading to Django 1.4 I can use LiveServerTestCase and fork casperjs in a subprocess:

```
from django.test.testcases import LiveServerTestCase
import os, subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

class CasperTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_initial_data', ]

    def test_my_testcase(self):
        p = Popen(['casperjs %s/caspertest.js' % os.path.dirname(__file__)], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
        output = p.stdout.read()
        print output
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [django-casper](https://github.com/dobarkod/django-casper). I started to use it a few days ago and it is just awesome!